# Php not receiving POST string

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I am trying to use the following function to post a single select option value to a `pChart` page. When I try to check the form data in developer tools it suggests the `name:datastring` pair is being posted to the PHP file. The Javascript file is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#players').on('change', function() {
        var dataString = $('#players option:selected').val();
        $.post("../pChart2.1.3/AllPillarsCoach.php",
               {name:dataString},
               "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
});
```

But it shows an empty array:

```
<?php
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($_POST)."br /";
    echo "</pre><br>";
    ...
?>
```

I have checked with `GET` as well with no success. I don't want a return to the browser as the PHP page renders an image and it doesn't appear too happy about being applied to a `div`.

Thanks for the replies so far my original, function was as follows which I truncated to try and make sure that the pChart was going to be parsed.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#players').on('change', function() {
        var dataString = $('#players option:selected').val();
                $.post("../pChart2.1.3/All.php",{name:dataString},"\nStatus: " + status,
                    function(status){
                alert("Data: " + dataString + "\Status: " + status);
            });

            });

        });
```

The developer tools with both versions suggests that the form data is being posted name= thw17po14 and parsed name: thw17po14. The alert shows both the dataString and the success message. I just want to take the post data as criteria for a query and the resulting chart will be accessed separately so no need for a return to the browser. Alert as it stands now shows the following after changing the "select option", again thanks for any help in advance.

```
            Data: thw17po14Status: <pre>array(1){
                ["name"]=>
                  string(9)"thw17po14"
                     }
                   </pre><br>
```

Comment: what are you getting in `alert(dataString)`?

Comment: The third argument to `jQuery.post()` should be a success callback, but you've supplied a string.

Comment: I think `dataString` is empty. Try this instead `var dataString = $(this).val();`

Comment: Make sure there is a value in dataString. Open up inspector and see what it sends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not able to comment yet - but now everything looks fine, doesn't it?

dataString is not empty and showing - also Status is showing the array:

```
Status: <pre>array(1){
            ["name"]=>
              string(9)"thw17po14"
                 }
               </pre><br>
```

It also shows your HTML. I'ld say you're done :)

Comment: Ok thanks I think I am nearly there, this is showing through the alert the dataString that has been posted, what do I have to do if I don't want the output from the PHP file, I am using the variable created and subsequently used as an argument in pChart.  Although it would be a better solution placing the image/png chart output from the PHP page it might be a step too far for me and I can just point a link to the page which will have been updated. I suppose it is a half-way house solution.

Comment: Further to my previous post, I realise this a different question to the original sorry, but when I try to insert the variable created from the $user = $_POST[name] into the pChart query it shows an empty image, no chart.  When I comment this out and provide the same string as in $user = 'thw17po14' the chart is shown.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: PHP should do it right - but may be try `$user = $_POST['name']` - otherwise `name` is an unknown constant and will at least throw a warning.
You also could test this by echoing the $user in your little PHP script when called with the alert of the return. [same as with the var_dump]

Comment: Yep this is the weird thing I can't get my head round.  When echoing the name back with either single quotes or without the correct echoed string comes back in the alert.  However within the PHP file with the query and chart on it, the page just shows an empty result set, as I said above just switching the variable source to the string rather than the $_POSTed  value shows a Chart.

Comment: Really strange - how about some internal character encoding issues? Try `if ($_POST['name'] == 'thw17po14') echo '123';` to see if the string is really the same? You probably also tried to set `$user` to the POST and echo the user variable - but that's all I can come up with for now.

Comment: The results of what you suggested were that the 123 echoed whether I had no quotes around thw17po14, single quotes 'thw17po14' or it even works for double quotes "thw17po14".  Could this be a utf8 issue I have the database set up as utf8_general_ci and the phpinfo.php is set to iso-8859-1?

Comment: yes and no - it's pretty normal characters and the mapping should be ok. You are using the same characters for setting $user directly. I am sorry - but I have no further idea at the moment. May be one last try. Do `$user = $_POST['name']; if($user == 'thw17po14') echo 'same value! '; if ($user === 'thw17po14') echo 'same type! ";`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you passing correct arguments to $.post?

It should be

```
$.post("../pChart2.1.3/AllPillarsCoach.php",
               {name:dataString},
               function(data){
                 alert(data);
               }
);
```

Check http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ for further reference.